# SQLite3 using table name as variable fails if its numeric/has special characters, but without variable it works (python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have problem with numeric variable while creating new table in database in Python.

Using normal string variable without any numbers or special characters does work without problems:

```
    name = "dataset"
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+ name + ' (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, u1 INTEGER NOT NULL)'
    c.execute(sql)
```

But this one does not work:

```
    name = "14-07"
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+ name + ' (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, u1 INTEGER NOT NULL)'
    c.execute(sql)
```

But the thing is that if I drop variable then it starts working:

```
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "14-07" (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, u1 INTEGER NOT NULL)'
    c.execute(sql)
```

Could some Python magician tell me how to make it work with variable in that numeric/special character case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because in your final snippet you've wrapped the table name in quotes.

Comment: But I can not do the same with variable can I?

Comment: Sure you can. Put the double quotes either side of the single quotes that end and begin the string. Or, even better, use string interpolation and put the quotes around that.